# How to Undo Smooth Shading - Blender

Tags: blender

Just wondering how to reverse smooth shading in Blender.

When the mesh is smooth shaded it's considerably slower to edit due to hardware overhead.

What are the combination of settings / options to undo smooth shading so I can get back to a hard / 'jaggy' polygon model for faster editing?

Answer (score 8):

In blender 2.8 it's: Select the object then go to the *Object -> Shade Flat*[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fist you go in **Object mode** and select your mesh. Then you go to your **Tools menu** (on the **left** of your screen) and select **Flat** thats under the **Shading** tab which is under your **Edit** tab.

Comment: On the right-hand side of the screen? There's a tools menu on the left side. Can't easily locate one on the right... The one on the left doesn't have a 'shading' tab though.